# function to print current module's name, also when called from another module

Tags: python, function, module

```
def a():
    print __name__
```

Is there any chance I can have such a function, but have it print the "correct" module name if imported by another module and called from there?

"Correct" module name should always be the one it is called from.

Comment: Which module would be the "correct" one? The importer or the importer?

Comment: you used the same words. You mean "importee"? From where it's called.

Comment: Yep, auto-correct didn't like the word "importee." Thanks.

Comment: Added the info to the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *sys* module provides a CPython specific way to lookup your caller:

```
sys._getframe(1).f_globals.get('__name__', '__main__')
```

The _getframe() function is documented *[here](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/sys.html#module-sys)*, and frame objects are documented *[here](http://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/datamodel.html#types)*.